# Unity3D Object 'Shoving' Mechanic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to make a 2D top-down perspective game in which I want to try and implement a shoving mechanic as a way of the player interacting with the environment or even enemies, but I can't seem to nail down the physics behind it.[image: Basic diagram to illustrate the concept]

(Player object (P) and interactive object (O))

My Question is: what is necessary to make this work properly? I've tried a few things out, such as having the information to add the force to the Rigidbody2D on P first and then on O and I'm trying to get it so that the player pushes the object in the direction it's facing, which I have a script for transform.up to face the mouse. I did also try to implement a dash mechanic to see if it would push an object further, however the physics meant that P would dash in a random direction as opposed to being towards the mouse

Comment: What may help other users that try to answer is the inclusion of the code you used for your past attempts. This way, we get a better idea of how you're currently approaching the issue, and can provide solutions that are more applicable to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

give the player object a rigidbody and a colider and the object a colider, should work no problem then!

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BoxCollider2D.html

should just work automatically then, Unity doing all the physics work for you

**edit**

if you want the object to be more strongly affected just reduce it's mass int he rigidbody in the inspector, or increase the players mass

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but what I'm after is the object being pushed with a strong impact on a button press, not just the unity physics engine doing what it does

Comment: you could use Rigidbody.addforce to the object on the button press http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

Comment: I have tried that but the problem is how can I get the direction I want it to be pushed

Comment: did you try using rigidbody.addforce(player.rigidbody.velocity * speed?)